# Why my Android app doesn't opening on my Android device after wireless debugging

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, error-handling, android-jetpack-compose

I create a simple app using Kotlin and Jetpack compose. When I run it and install it on my Android device using wireless debugging it doesn't open. I am pretty sure there aren't any syntax error or any error in my code

Although here is my code https://github.com/kuvipro11/AndroidDev-.git

Comment: Have you checked logcat for errors?

Comment: Please don't link to your code. Links can break, or linked content can change (especially on github!), making your question useless for others with similar problems. [Edit] your question and include the relevant code here as a [mcve].  Add logging to your code, check the logs for errors.